# Clase para para cargar scripts y css en PHP

Tags: php, html, poo

necesito un método para cargar archivos css y javascript dinámicamente en cada pagina, para no cargar archivos innecesarios y mejorar el rendimiento. Cree una clase en php que funciona, pero quiero saber si existe un método mejor. No uso ningún framework PHP

```
/**
* Clase encargada de cargar los scripts
*/
class Autoload
{
    public static function loadJS($toLoad) {
        // Definir los scripts a cargar 
        $jquery = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js";
        // Classes javascript
        $logClass = "views/app/js/cls/Log.js";
        $userClass = "views/app/js/cls/User.js";
        $alertClass = "views/app/js/cls/Alert.js";
        // Funciones generales
        $generals = "views/app/js/generals.js";
        // Funciones de logeo y registro
        $loginScript = "views/app/js/login.js";
        $registerScript = "views/app/js/register.js";   
        // Bootstrap
        // Tether
        $libsTether = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js";
        $libsBootstrap = "views/libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js";
        // Array de enlaces
        $src = Array(
            'jquery' => $jquery,
            'logClass' => $logClass,
            'userClass' => $userClass,
            'alertClass' => $alertClass,
            'generals' => $generals,
            'loginScript' => $loginScript,
            'registerScript' => $registerScript,
            'libsTether' => $libsTether,
            'libsBootstrap' => $libsBootstrap
            );
        /* Plantilla del array $toLoadJS obtenido
            $toLoad = Array(
                'jquery' => true,
                'logClass' => true,
                'userClass' => true,
                'alertClass' => true,
                'generals' => true,
                'loginScript' => true,
                'registerScript' => true,
                'libsTether' => true,
                'libsBootstrap' => true>
                );
        */      
        $html = '';
        foreach ($toLoad as $key => $value) {
            if ($value) {
                $script = ' <script src="' . $src[$key] . '"></script>' . "\n";                 $html = $html . $script;
            }
        }
        return $html;
    }
    public static function loadCSS($toLoad){
        // Definir las rutas de los estilos
        // Plantillas de paginas
        $hometemplate ='views/app/css/hometemplate.css';
        $registertemplate = 'views/app/css/registertemplate.css';
                    // Array de enlaces
        $href = Array(
            'hometemplate' => $hometemplate,
            'registertemplate' => $registertemplate
            );
        /* Plantilla del array $toLoadCSS obtenido
            $toLoad = Array(
                'hometemplate' => false,
                'registertemplate' => false
                );
        */
        $html = '';
        foreach ($toLoad as $key => $value) {
            if($value){
                $style = '<link href="' . $href[$key] . '" rel="stylesheet">' . "\n";
                $html = $html . $style;
            }
        }

        return $html;
    }
}
```

Y en mis paginas individuales pongo esto:

```
  $toLoadJS = Array(
   'jquery' => true,
   'logClass' => true,
   'userClass' => true,
   'alertClass' => true,
   'generals' => true,
   'loginScript' => true,
   'registerScript' => false,
   'libsTether' => false,
   'libsBootstrap' => true
  );
 $toLoadCSS = Array(
   'hometemplate' => true,
   'registertemplate' => false
   );
   echo Autoload::loadCSS($toLoadCSS);
   echo Autoload::loadJS($toLoadJS);
```

Comment: Quizas lo mejor es usar, http://requirejs.org/

Answer (score -1):

Entiendo que quieres crear una hoja o pagina externa donde guardar tu CSS con tu estilo , y/o, tu PHP con tus métodos, para luego cargar estas en cada una de tus paginas individuales.

Si es así te invito a que revises este enlace donde te explican como usar la etiqueta **link** . Para llamar a una hoja externa de CSS. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
```

En cuanto al PHP. Mira cual de estas dos opciones se adaptan mejor a tus necesidades.

**include**
http://php.net/manual/es/function.include.php

**require_once**
http://php.net/manual/es/function.require-once.php

Este ultimo enlace intenta explicar la diferencia entre los dos.
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp

Espero que esto solucione tus dudas.